# NEAR cli v3.2 asks for 3 confirmations for each ledger public key

Tags: nearprotocol, near

Every time I generate a command on the CLI which requires ledger, it asks for access to the public key on the device three times before proceeding. The transaction itself is successful (or fails) independently of this. Why?

(details removed)

```
$ near call some_contract.near some_method --useLedgerKey "44'/397'/0'/0'/1'"
Make sure to connect your Ledger and open NEAR app
Scheduling a call: some_contract.some_method()
Doing account.functionCall()
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
Approved
Using public key: ed25519:MY_PUBLIC_KEY
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
Approved
Using public key: ed25519:MY_PUBLIC_KEY
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
Approved
Using public key: ed25519:MY_PUBLIC_KEY
Waiting for confirmation on Ledger...
Ledger app version: 1.1.6
Transaction Id etc etc etc................................
```